# Git clone stops working suddenly?

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

I use capistrano to deploy my rails app. Today I noticed that it failed, then rolled back. The specific error is:

```
** github.com[0:207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out 
** fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out) 
** Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/username/pygments.rb.git'
```

If I SSH into the server and run

`git clone 'git://github.com/username/pygments.rb.git' test`

It times out... if I run it locally however on my computer it works perfectly.

Also -- If i use the http:// link it clones successfully. Only the git-read-only link is what times out.

I have changed nothing in my code and have deployed probably 100 times with this code.

I also added that particular IP to CSF and it didn't help either (I haven't made any server changes either to firewall, etc).

Is there any way I can debug this, or any input as to what I should be whitelisting (if that's even the right answer at all..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the server is blocked from accessing github. Make sure your firewall is allowing TCP over port 9418 to your server to get to github, or try switching to `https://github.com/...` instead of `git://github.com/...`

The fact that you can get to it on your local machine but the server cannot, seems to indicate that someone changed the firewall to block your server from using that port.